# Android Application Emulator keeps stopping on React Native

Tags: android, react-native, mobile-application

I was editing one of the '.js' files and after saving my work after some changes, when I typed 'rr' to refresh application on the emulator, I kept getting this message.

Android Application Emulator keeps stopping
App info
Close app

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1b7I.png)

After creating **Form.js** and under a components folder in my project in the visual studio code editor and importing it in my **Login.js** that's where the error started to occur. IDK what I did wrong. I'm new to React Native and am just learning.

**Form.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { 
    StyleSheet,  
    Text, 
    View,
    TextInput
  } from 'react-native';

export default class Login extends Component<{}> {
      render(){
          return(
              <View style={styles.container}>
                <TextInput style={styles.inputBox} 
                  underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)' 
                  placeholder="Email"
                  placeholderTextColor = "#ffffff"
                   />
                <TextInput style={styles.inputBox} 
                  underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)' 
                  placeholder="Password"
                  placeholderTextColor = "#ffffff"
                   />
                </View>
          )
      }
  }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container : {
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center'
},
inputBox: {
  width:300,
  backgroundColor:'rgba(255,255,255,0.3)',
  borderRadius: 25,
  paddingHorizontal: 16,
  fontSize: 16,
  color:'#ffffff',
  marginVertical: '10'

}
});
```

**Login.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { 
    StyleSheet,  
    Text, 
    View,
    StatusBar
  } from 'react-native';

import Logo from '../components/Logo';
import Form from '../components/Form';

export default class Login extends Component<{}> {
render () {
return(
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Logo/>  
    <Form/>      
  </View>
)
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container : {
  backgroundColor: '#29b6f6',
  flex: 1,
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
}
});
```

Comment: There is because of your last changes in your code.  
somehow it's crash your application.

just stop node.  
rollback your changes.  
then again hit command `react-native run-android`

Comment: Thank you for responding @ParasKorat. I rollbacked my changes, stopped node by exiting and closing command line, re opened command line, cd'd to proper directory folder, and ran the [react-native run-android] command. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. try this one, uninstall the application from an emulator, clean your android gradle by this command first "cd android" then ".\gradlew clean". and run again.

Comment: @ParasKorat, I followed your steps. Here's what I did in order: 1. Clicked 'App info' then clicked 'uninstall'. 2. I then closed the node cli then then my command prompt. 3. I reopend command prompt and cd'd to (C:\Users\Clint\Desktop\DesktopTings\Reactnative\lulock>cd android) then ran [gradlew clean]. 4. Opened up an emulator. 5. cd'd back to root project and [react-native run-android]. Still got the error. I edited my post to show in detail what files I made changes to which caused the application to crash.

Comment: try this answer i have written below

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your reminder, where can i find the location to click 'corrected answer'

Comment: below up-down vote button, you will find a right tick. just click on that. when it turns into a green that means that the answer is correct. you can only select one answer as a right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution
Your application is crashed because of this props **underlineColorAndroid="rgba(0,0,0,0)"** in your TextInput and also minor change in inputBox style remove string value **marginVertical: "10"** to **marginVertical: 10**

**Form.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput } from "react-native";

export default class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.inputBox}
          // underlineColorAndroid="rgba(0,0,0,0)"<---Comment this code---
          placeholder="Email"
          placeholderTextColor="#ffffff"
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.inputBox}
          // underlineColorAndroid="rgba(0,0,0,0)"<---Comment this code---
          placeholder="Password"
          placeholderTextColor="#ffffff"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  inputBox: {
    width: 300,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.3)",
    borderRadius: 25,
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
    fontSize: 16,
    color: "#ffffff",
    marginVertical: 10 <-----Remove string to number---
  }
});
```

**Output**:--

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @ParasKorat. Changing the string type to integer type via correct syntax is what fixed it. It's working well, as far as commenting out the //underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0), is it because I had used it incorrectly? After reading https://codedaily.io/tutorials/3/Remove-the-Underline-from-Android-TextInputs-in-React-Native, it lists somewhere near the first half of the page that the syntax should be underlineColorAndroid="#ff0000", underlineColorAndroid="red", or underlineColorAndroid="rgb(255,0,0)".

Comment: Could it be that I had done "rgb(x,x,x,x)" when it should've been "rgb(x,x,x)"? Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: @Supreme2717 If this is helpful and solve your problem then please don't forget to tick as correct answer. it helps others to find a solution easily.